# Why does Princess Bubblegum remember time differently at different ages?

Tags: adventure-time

In the season three episode, "Too Young," Princess Bubblegum has de-aged herself to being 13 again. In her de-aged form, she seems to have all her memories and knowledge from her 18-year-old self, but she is the same age as Finn and displays similar levels of maturity and, well, behavior.

However, at the end of the episode, when she is re-aged to her 18-year-old self, Finn nervously suggests they kiss again and Peebles says something to the effect of, "Oh Finn, that was like five years ago."

**What explains this time difference?** Was she making a joke about their age difference? Or does she remember that event taking place five years ago because (in a literal sense) her body was five years younger when it happened? If so, then why does her younger-aged version of herself retain her older self's memories?

Comment: Well, it WAS 'like' five years ago...it's entirely possible that Princess Bubblegum was being literal.

Answer (score 7):

As you've noted, Bubblegum has continuity of memory in her differently biologically aged forms.  The only possibility is thus that she is humorously referring to the difference in biological ages, instead of truthfully stating that she believes that five years have passed since she kissed Finn.  Think about the ramifications if this weren't true-- she would have to "remember" five years' worth of events that never happened.